# Surface integral to double integral containing a line integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I stumbled upon the following surface integral and I'm not sure if my understanding of surface integrals is correct:
I need to integrate the function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{z^4}$ over the surface $\Sigma=\{(x,y,z) : z = (x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}, z \in [1,2]\}$

My approach was to integrate $f$ over a series of circumferences with radii $\frac{1}{z}$: $$\int_{\Sigma} f\  dS=\int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\gamma(t))\,\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|\,dt\,dz$$ where $\gamma(t) = (\frac{1}{z}cos(t),\frac{1}{z}sin(t),z)$, thus obtaining:
$$\int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{z^4} \frac{1}{z}\,dt\,dz = \frac{15\pi}{32}$$

is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Do you not know a procedure for parametrizing a surface and using the parametrization to evaluate a surface integral?

Comment: @TedShifrin i do, i normally should find a parameterization of the surface and evaluate the integral $\int f(\sigma(u,v)) \| \partial_{u}\sigma \wedge \partial_{v}\sigma\|\,du\,dv$ , but i was wondering if the method i showed was valid too: It amounts to slicing the surface with planes normal to the $xy$ plane, integrate the intersections and sum them up

Comment: No, it’s not valid. Approximating a cone by a cylinder does not work. And where did you get $1/z^4$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, i fixed the error: the function is $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{z^4}$.
I don't really get the approximation you mentioned, since z is fixed in the inner integral, isn't my parameterization representing a circumference parallel to the $xy$ plane, of radius $\frac{1}{z}$ and at height $z$?

Comment: So you replaced $\| \partial_u \sigma \wedge \partial_v \sigma \|$ by $\| \partial_u \sigma \|$. That's incorrect.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Sorry, i'm not trying to be argue, i just can't really understand why my reasoning is wrong: why would summing up the values of a series of curvilinear integrals be wrong?

Comment: Do you understand what $\| \partial_u \sigma \wedge \partial_v \sigma \|$ means?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval it would be the absolute magnitude of the normal vector to a point on the surface

Comment: Try finding the surface area of a cone using your approach. You should see pictorially precisely what’s wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin It all makes sense now! Apparently my method gives back the area of the surface projection on the plane, thanks.